# SSL Certificates from nginx only works in Windows IE and Chrome

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, https, certificate-authority

I have a wildcard certificate and got it signed by AlphaSSL. I followed the steps from here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains to set it up on my nginx server which is used as a reverse proxy for multiple web sites and applications.

At the moment it is only set up on my Joomla website - https://www.webbsc.at

It works fine on Windows IE 11 and Windows Chrome. It is failing on Windows Firefox, Mac OS X with any browser and Android Chrome. I didn't have the chance to try it out with other browsers / OS so far.

Firefox says that it cannot identify the issuer (sec_error_unknown_issuer) but I have added the intermediate certificate. Also Chrome in Windows can show me the correct certification hierarchy, while Firefox only shows my certificate.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

Configurations for the certificate I've tried so far:

- **my-cert**, **intermediate**
- **my-cert**, **intermediate**, **root**
- **my-cert**, **root**, **intermediate**

all three work in IE, Chrome in Windows, none work in any other browser

When I've tried a different intermediate certificate it didn't work in Windows anymore either, so it should be the correct intermediate one.

Once again - when I open the Firefox or Mac OS X details about the certificate I can't see the intermediate + root certificate in the hierarchy. In Windows I see them, as well as on the Websites for testing SSL (provided by the first answer)

**Solution:**

As you can read in the comments of the answer, I had a wrong intermediate certificate which somehow worked better than other the other wrong certificate I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is something wrong with the intermediate certificate . If you verify your certificate using tools from [SSLShopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) or [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) , both are returning errors in the certificate chain.

Comment: Could it be a problem how I've concatenated it, maybe a missing `new line`? Or is it rather a problem with the certificate as such?

Comment: How many certificates have you concatenated? According to GlobalSign you need three: https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1290470-install-certificate---nginx . Also verify if the intermediate certificate is the right one: https://www.alphassl.com/support/install-root-certificate.html

Comment: I've updated my question with more information, which certificates I have, ... going to check out the links you've posted, thx

Comment: I'm not sure about this one but your AlphaSSL certificate says "valid from August 2, 2011 to August 2, 2022" which according to the AlphaSSL site belongs to "SHA-256 Orders Prior to March 31, 2014". "SHA-256 - Orders March 31, 2014 and After" should say "Valid until: 20 February 2024"

Comment: aaaa damn - I read the year wrong, for some reason I thought it's 2015, sorry 'bout that - I'm checking now the latest one, hope this was the only mistake I made